# WooCommerce override cart prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am currently working with WooCommerce. the following function hooks into "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" and changes the value of the product. This works fine with simple products, However this doesnt work with variations:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'wwp_variable_add_cart_price' );
function wwp_variable_add_cart_price( $cart_object ) {
$current_user = new WP_User(wp_get_current_user()->id);
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
foreach ($user_roles as $roles) {
    if ($roles == 'administrator'){
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            $wholesale = get_post_meta( $value['product_id'], '_wholesale_price', true );
            if ($wholesale){    
            $value['data']->price = $wholesale;
            }
}}}}
```

Do i need to do something different for variations? Or should the above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the following line of code:

```
$wholesalev = get_post_meta( $value['data']->variation_id, '_wholesale_price', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$cart_item['data']->get_id();` now works for both simple products and variations.

```
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

    $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

    $new_price = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wholesale_price', true );

    $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $new_price ) );

    }
```